# Django: Two models share a many-To-many relationship with one model

Tags: mysql, django

I have three models: Internal_Apps, Services and External_Apps.The relationship between Internal_Apps and Services is internal_app can have many services and services belong to many internal_apps.I have defined this relationship through the junction table.However, the External_Apps has same relationship with Services.Could I use the same junction table to define the relationship between External_Apps and Services or make a separate junction table for External_Apps and Services? What is the best practice for this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `through` for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: I am a new to Django. I read the provided link. It describes to how to use a costume junction table. The junction table i have is one Django auto creates.